# How does this XSS payloads works for this code?

Tags: javascript, xss, security

I am trying to  solve this xss challenge: https://sandbox.pwnfunction.com/warmups/jefff.html

Where I found this code:

```javascript
<h2 id="maname"></h2>
<script>
    let jeff = (new URL(location).searchParams.get('jeff') || "JEFFF")
    let ma = ""
    eval(`ma = "Ma name ${jeff}"`)
    setTimeout(_ => {
        maname.innerText = ma
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

After analysis of js code.
First, I added the jeff parameter in the URL `https://sandbox.pwnfunction.com/warmups/jefff.html?jeff=" Pikachu"` and I got some output like this `Ma name Pikachu`.

Now I entered some malicious data in jeff parameter. so I entered `?jeff="alert(1337)"`  Now I got an error
[image]

if we go through code why this happened :

```
<h2 id="maname"></h2>
<script>
    //get jeff value from jeff param.
    let jeff = "alert(1337)"
    let ma = ""
    //put jeff value
    eval(`ma = "Ma name "alert(1337)""`)
    //here we see that of course error is arise
    setTimeout(_ => {
        maname.innerText = ma
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

now we use another similar payload where we add only `-` in the payload and the rest of the payload is the same `?jeff="-alert(1337)-"` . Here we are not found any console error while we get alert box 1337.
if we see the eval function we found :

```
<h2 id="maname"></h2>
<script>
    //get jeff value from jeff param.
    let jeff = "-alert(1337)-"
    let ma = ""
    //put jeff value 
    eval(`ma = "Ma name "-alert(1337)-""`)
    setTimeout(_ => {
        maname.innerText = ma
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

My Expected output: some console error.
Actual output: pop-up alert box.
Why this payload is not giving a console error? how this payload works here? what is the purpose of using the `-` operator in this payload?

Comment: @Liam I don't see how it applies here.

Comment: @Gander feel free to suggest an edit to address easily fixable issues.

Comment: @Liam Please retract this vote. The usage of `eval` is for educational purpose in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A string literal followed by a function call is an error:

```js
"foo"alert("bar");
```

A string literal followed **by an operator** followed by a function call is **not** an error:

```js
"foo"-alert("bar");
```